# Send Outlook Calendar event to group, and prevent each member from seeing other members emails

Tags: events, outlook, calendar, invite

I am trying to send a unique calendar event to each member of a group/distribution list in Outlook. I can cc all members but that will reveal all email address to each member in the group. Does anyone know the correct way to do this.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- I can think of using BCC'ing invitees is to forward the meeting as an iCal. Add the attendees to the message BCC field and give a try.
- Using Outlook or any messaging api's, the above is not possible, because meeting requests don't use a "Bcc" field. The equivalent of that field is reserved for inviting resources.